# Code structure for 3rd party API calls

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

The Problem:

I need to create a HttpService (Interface + Implementation) within an application that will be responsible for communicating with an external API service. There are three types of data that I need to download from a Data Web Store:

1. Available Data (list of data packages that are available for
   purchasing)
2. Purchased Data (list of data packages that the client has already purchased)
3. Discounted Data (list of data packages that can be purchased at a discounted price)

Apart from the Request URI, which is required for all three endpoints, the second endpoint also needs a valid client ID.

The Solution:

I am considering two options (request URI will not be needed in this case):

1. Two generic requests with different parameters:

```
    Task GetAsync(string requestUri, Func<Stream, Task> callback); // for the 1st and 3rd requests
    Task GetAsync(string requestUri, int clientId, Func<Stream, Task> callback); // for the 2nd request
```

2. Three separate requests (one for each endpoint):

```
    Task GetAvailableDataPackageCollectionAsync(Func<Stream, Task> callback); // for the 1st request
    Task GetPurchasedDataPackageCollectionAsync(int clientId, Func<Stream, Task> callback); //for the 2nd request
    Task GetDiscountedDataPackageCollectionAsync(Func<Stream, Task> callback); //for the 3rd request
```

The Confusion:

I am wondering what is the preferred way to do it (or third way).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you anticipate a callback? Why don't you return with `Task<Stream>`?

Comment: The fastest explanation is because of this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75564472/how-to-properly-separate-api-calls-from-file-storage-service-in-a-clean-architec

Comment: I think you could use the second one, and make `GetAsync` private method to be reused within the second approach. You could also remove `Collection` and use something like `GetAvailableDataPackagesAsync` no need to use collection, just use `Task<Stream>`

Comment: Suggestion for Private method noted and accepted. But I am not sure how to return stream with "return await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()" if the HttpResponseMessage is disposed? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75564472/how-to-properly-separate-api-calls-from-file-storage-service-in-a-clean-architec